# convert time to seconds struct in c

Tags: c

The above code is to convert a time to seconds in c using struct I dont know how to use stdarg in function please help me...

i created a struct called time.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdarg.h> 

typedef struct time { 
    int hours, minutes, seconds; 
} Time;
    
int printTimeInSeconds(int n,int,...){
    Time res;
    res.t1=time1.hours*3600+time1.minutes*60+time1.seconds;
    res.t2=time2.hours*3600+time2.minutes*60+time2.seconds;
    res.t3=time3.hours*3600+time3.minutes*60+time3.seconds;
    res.t4=time4.hours*3600+time4.minutes*60+time4.seconds;
      
    return res;
}
    
int main() { 
    Time time1, time2, time3, time4; 
    scanf("%d:%d:%d", &time1.hours, &time1.minutes, &time1.seconds); 
    scanf("%d:%d:%d", &time2.hours, &time2.minutes, &time2.seconds); 
    scanf("%d:%d:%d", &time3.hours, &time3.minutes, &time3.seconds); 
    scanf("%d:%d:%d", &time4.hours, &time4.minutes, &time4.seconds); 
    printTimeInSeconds(1, time1); 
    printTimeInSeconds(2, time1, time2); 
    printTimeInSeconds(3, time1, time2, time3); 
    printTimeInSeconds(4, time1, time2, time3, time4); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Input:

```
00:00:01 
01:00:00 
12:59:59 
00:01:00
```

Output:

```
1 
3601 
50400 
50460
```

I wrote the function part wrongly and please explain how to use stdarg in this function

Comment: There are no `t1`, `t2`, etc. members in the `Time` structure. What is `res.t1` supposed to be?

Comment: The function is declared to return `int`, why are you returning `res`?

Comment: There is no `printf()` (or other output functions), so no output.  Looks like another's code for OP to fix.  Perhaps best to let OP detail what is misunderstood as "I wrote the function part wrongly" is vague.  @Hymdal, please report the compiler errors you received and which ones were not clear.

Comment: You don't need `int,` before `...` in the function signature. You only include declarations for the fixed arguments, not the variable arguments.

Comment: Are you sure you need to use `<stdarg.h>`?  Does the `printTimeInSeconds` function really need to accept a variable numbers of times?  That seems like a strange way to arrange things.

Comment: Google "c variadic function tutorial". SO is not a tutoring service.

Comment: https://ideone.com/VmtHbU

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link for stdarg with a well explained [example](https://publications.gbdirect.co.uk//c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html).
Explanation for [va_list](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/va_list/)
And an explanation for [va_arg, va_start and va_end](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/va-arg-va-copy-va-end-va-start?view=msvc-170)

I used Visual Studio to Compile.
First you have to decide if your function should print or if you want the result.
I print the result and return it.
In the function `printTimeInSeconds()` create type `va_list`(ap) for `va_start` and `va_arg`
Initialize type `va_list`(ap) with `va_start` for future retrive of passed arguments with `va_arg`.
`va_arg` returns value of (ap) as type of second parameter(Time) and changes pointer(ap) to next Argument.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdarg.h> 

#pragma warning (disable:4996)

typedef struct {
    int hours, minutes, seconds;
} Time;

int printTimeInSeconds(int n_args,...) {
    int res = 0;
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, n_args);
    for (int i = 1; i <= n_args; ++i)
    {
        //Better solution from Jonathan Leffler
        Time t = va_arg(ap, Time);
        res += (t.hours * 60 + t.minutes) * 60 + t.seconds;
        /*My old solution
             //va_arg(ap, int) returns the value of type(int) and moves pointer(ap)+= size of type(int)
        res += va_arg(ap, int) * 3600;      //hours
        res += va_arg(ap, int) * 60;        //minutes
        res += va_arg(ap, int);             //seconds
             //va_arg(ap, int) type is always int because the struct is only int
        */
    }
    //va_end before return of function
    va_end(ap);
    //if you want your function to print
    printf("%d\n", res);
    //if you need the result
    return res;
}

int main() {
    Time time1, time2, time3, time4;
    scanf("%d:%d:%d", &time1.hours, &time1.minutes, &time1.seconds);
    scanf("%d:%d:%d", &time2.hours, &time2.minutes, &time2.seconds);
    scanf("%d:%d:%d", &time3.hours, &time3.minutes, &time3.seconds);
    scanf("%d:%d:%d", &time4.hours, &time4.minutes, &time4.seconds);
    printTimeInSeconds(1, time1);
    printTimeInSeconds(2, time1, time2);
    printTimeInSeconds(3, time1, time2, time3);
    printTimeInSeconds(4, time1, time2, time3, time4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since `Time` values are passed to the function, I think it would be better/safer to use code like this in the function: `for (int i = 1; i <= n_args; ++i) { Time t = va_arg(ap, Time); res += (t.hours * 60 + t.minutes) * 60 + t.seconds; }`.  You're likely to get away your technique with the current structure, but other structures with padding at the end (in particular) could cause your code to fail.  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ For example, if someone created `typedef struct Gizmo { int value1; double value2; int value3; } Gizmo;` and passed 1-4 of those to the analogue of `printTimeInSeconds()`, then using `int v1 = va_arg(ap, int); double v2 = va_arg(ap, double); int v3 = va_arg(ap, int);` is likely to get erroneous data into `v1`, `v2`, `v3`.